# Django/Python: How can I make the following number increment (not in database)

Tags: python, django, auto-increment

I would like to create a number like:

```
000000000001
```

to save to the database. I obviously cannot increment in this fashion (I don't think) in a database, so I'm looking for the most efficient method for pulling the previous number from the database and incrementing it by 1 to create the next record:

```
000000000002
```

and so on...

If I store the first number manually, can I do some sort of manual typing to make it hold its number of zeros? I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the leading zeroes are just formatting.

```
>>> "%012d" % ( 1, )
'000000000001'
>>> "%012d" % ( 2, )
'000000000002'
```

Use an ordinary integer and format it to have lots of leading zeroes.

Comment: And to be sure, "%012d" % (22,) evaluates to '000000000022', just as you would want.

Comment: And, Travis Bradshaw. BTW, I went to high school with a Travis Bradshaw in Boise, ID.

Comment: why not use itertools and save yourself all that typing?

Comment: sorry, nvm, after re-reading the question I see he's just trying to increment once ... at first I thought he was trying to loop over all of the items.

Comment: For formatting with leading zeros you can also use zfill(n). For your example above: [variable].zfill(12)

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a super tricky way to do this using the itertools library and a generator function.

```
from itertools import product, imap

def stringdigit(num_digits=10, start = None):
    """A generator function which returns string versions of a large iterated number with
    leading zeros. start allows you to define a place to begin the iteration"""
    treatfun = lambda x: ''.join(x)
    for n in imap(treatfun, product('0123456789', repeat = num_digits)):
        if start == None or n > start:
            yield n
```

This creates an iterator which will return the "zero-padded string form" that you need.  It works using the product function which iteratively returns repeated combinations from an iterable in "sorted order".  The num_digits argument specifies how many total digits you would like returned.  `start` specifies a place to begin the iteration from (say if you wanted to start from 1111111).

`product` comes with the python 2.6 release.  If your using something before that for some reason then use this as the product definition.  Taken from the docs [here](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#product).

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    # product('ABCD', 'xy') --> Ax Ay Bx By Cx Cy Dx Dy
    # product(range(2), repeat=3) --> 000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

You can use this function in in a for-loop as an interator:

```
for num in stringdigit(num_digits = 7):
    #do stuff with num
```

Hope that helps.
-Will